# Why is my _root here stuck at null?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I've stepped through the code of

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GenericBinaryTree
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BinaryTree<int> B = new BinaryTree<int>();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
            {
                B.Add(rnd.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue));
            }
            B.Print();
        }
    }

    class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        public class Node
        {
            public T val { get; set; }
            public Node left { get; set; }
            public Node right { get; set; }
        }

        private Node _root = null;

        public void Add ( T newval )
        {
            Add(newval, _root);
        }

        private void Add ( T newval, Node root )
        {
            if(root != null)
            {
                if(newval.CompareTo(root.val) < 0)
                    Add(newval, root.left);
                else if(newval.CompareTo(root.val) > 0)
                    Add(newval, root.right);
            }
            else
            {
                root = new Node() { val = newval, left = null, right = null };
            }
        }

        public void Print ( )
        {
            if(_root != null)
                PrintValAndDescendants(_root);     
        }

        private void PrintValAndDescendants ( Node  n )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            if(n.right != null) PrintValAndDescendants(n.right);
            if(n.left != null) PrintValAndDescendants(n.left);
        }
    }
}
```

and I can't figure out why my `_root` isn't getting set when

```
Add(newval, _root);
```

initially gets called. The block

```
else
{
   root = new Node() { val = newval, left = null, right = null };
}
```

should make it non-`null`, but that's not the case ... unless there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`root` is a variable that is local in scope to the `Add` function. Initially, `root` and `_root` point to the same object, but by assigning it a `new Node` you only change what object `root` points to. It does not change what `_root` points to.

You need to either set `_root` directly, or make `root` a [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) parameter.

Comment: I thought a `Node` is a `Object` and therefore is already passed by reference.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference, but references to that object are not passed by reference. i.e. if you call a mutating method on the `Node`, both `_root` and `root` will reflect that change. If on the other hand you just assign a value to `_root` or `root`, the other one will not reflect that change.